# Own controls similar to TextBox in C# Windows application

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls

Create own TextBox, Button etc control as own control using User control in C# Windows application, is this good idea?
I wanted make consistency for through out the application. Suppose if I want to change the Textbox border color then all forms textbox updated with this changes. It's just an example.
Please suggest me.

Comment: Derive your own class from TextBox and change properties in the constructor.  Compile and you've got a new control on the top of the toolbox that you can use over and over again.

Comment: Seems good idea, Please can you give me some example link?

Comment: Yeah, if you don't want to use WPF and no standard control, write custom classes derived from standard control classes. You can specify the properties there. What's the problem with that? +1 to Hans.

Comment: public class MyTextBox : TextBox { public MyTextBox() { //set properties here} }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't recommend using UserControl just for consistency. If application skinning is what you are after, look into WPF. It makes it relatively simple to skin an application (or even a window, or smaller groups)

Here is an article on skinning with WPF: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19782/Creating-a-Skinned-User-Interface-in-WPF

Another alternative, staying within Windows Forms, is creating a class that inherits from TextBox, and using that class throughout the application. The [Factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) would work well here. You could even adapt it to multiple skins.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you but issue is I don't have good knowledge in WPF.

Comment: Unless you have a large existing application, using WPF is more than worth the effort. Trends seem to indicate that Windows Forms will be obsolete in the not-too-distant future. I highly recommend at least dabbling with WPF. The experience will be very valuable.

Comment: Thanks Frey, for your suggestion. I will plan accordingly.

Comment: WPF is a good option. Styles can be defined for control that can be applicable to the entire application.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bad idea to provide custom controls that match your "User Experience" (UX). It really just depends on what you are trying to accomplish with your program.

Comment: Yeh...But I am thinking more coding part is required to accomplish in this way. So I am planning to use standard controls only.